# I need to refactor an ancient piece of Perl code with defined(@array) and defined(%hash)

Tags: perl, cgi, movabletype

I'm running an ancient version of Movable Type that works just fine for me. However, I began to receive the following server errors:

```
defined(@array) is deprecated at /home/public_html/cgi-bin/mt/extlib/Locale/Maketext.pm line 623.
defined(%hash) is deprecated at /home/public_html/cgi-bin/mt/extlib/Locale/Maketext.pm line 623.
```

I found the line in question:

```
if defined(%{$module . "::Lexicon"}) or defined(@{$module . "::ISA"});
```

Is the following the correct way to refactor this line?

```
if %{$module . "::Lexicon"} or @{$module . "::ISA"};
```

If so, why? If not, why not? I'd like to understand better what happened to `defined(@array)` and `defined(%hash)`.

**UPDATE:** I also found a similar issue on line 367 of `CGI.pm`:

```
if (defined(@QUERY_PARAM) && !defined($initializer)) {
```

I rewrote this as follows but I'm still not sure if it's right:

```
if (@QUERY_PARAM && $initializer) {
```

I can see how `@QUERY_PARAM` could confirm that it exists, but I'm probably not setting the second condition that `$initializer` does *not* exist, and I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: `!defined($initializer)` is still correct -- you would want CGI.pm:367 to now read `if (@QUERY_PARAM && !defined($initializer) {`

Comment: @mob Whoops! I see I was a little overzealous here.

Comment: `defined(@array)` and `defined(%hash)` *never* made sense. So we can't tell you how to fix it without knowing what the buggy code is trying to accomplish. It's likely the code is trying to check if the array/hash is empty or not, in which case you can simply use `@array` or `%hash` (in scalar context).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ perl -w -Mdiagnostics -e 'print defined(@array)'

Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at -e
        line 1 (#1)
    (F) defined() is not useful on arrays because it
    checks for an undefined scalar value.  If you want to see if the
    array is empty, just use if (@array) { # not empty } for example.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at -e line 1.
```

---

`$ [perldoc -f defined]`(http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#defined)

```
...

Use of "defined" on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is no longer
supported. It used to report whether memory for that aggregate
had ever been allocated. You should instead use a simple test
for size:

     if (@an_array) { print "has array elements\n" }
     if (%a_hash)   { print "has hash members\n"   }
```

---

The `defined(@array)` construction never did what users expected it to do, and what it actually did was not that useful, so it was removed from the language (and deprecated in the version of Perl you are using). The way to fix it, as the diagnostics and docs suggest, is to just use `@array` rather than `defined(@array)` in boolean context.

Comment: Er, no, it didn't indicate whether the array is empty - it indicated if the array had ever been used. This prints true on older perls even though the array is now empty: @a = 1; @a = (); print "true\n" if defined @a;

Comment: The bad lines of code are from an old version of Locale::Maketext and seemed to be trying to test whether a module had already been loaded. In current release, they've just removed the 'defined'.

Answer (score 0):

As mob said, the solution is just to do `if (@array)...` or `if (%hash)...`.

However, for anyone too curious, you can inspect the symbol table to see if that variable has ever been autovivified.  More however, however, there is (almost) no reason to ever do this.  All it would tell you is if you are the first line of code to use that variable.  Which is 5 nines of useless.

But for that 6th significant digit, here's how you do it.  The only use case I even know of is in `Carp` where it checks for some variables in the calling namespace without polluting it in the process.

This only works for global, non-lexical, variables. Global is undeclared, `use vars qw//`, and `our()`.  Lexical is `my()` and `state()`.  The symbol table is the special hash that contains all of the global symbol names in your package.

```perl
use Data::Dump qw/pp/;

pp \ %Z::;
{}

$Z::foo = "foo scalar";

pp \ %Z::;
do {
  my $a = { foo => *Z::foo };
  $a->{foo} = \"foo scalar";
  $a;
}

print "symbol exists\n" if exists $Z::{foo};
symbol exists

print "symbol and array exists\n" if $Z::{foo} and defined *{$Z::{foo}}{ARRAY};

pp \ %Z::;
do {
  my $a = { foo => *Z::foo };
  $a->{foo} = \"foo scalar";
  $a;
}

print "symbol and array does not exist\n" unless $Z::{foo} and defined *{$Z::{foo}}{ARRAY};
symbol and array does not exist

pp \ %Z::;
do {
  my $a = { foo => *Z::foo };
  $a->{foo} = \"foo scalar";
  $a;
}
```